# Checkbook value automatically sending on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to pass a checkbox value of modal form using AJAX but without checking the check-box. Whenever I click on the submit button it automatically selects the checkbox and sends its value. Why is all that happening?

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) { ?> checked <?php } ?>>
        Remember me
    </label>
</div>
```

```js
$('#login_Modal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $('#loginUsername').val();
    var password = $('#loginPassword').val();
    var remember = $('input[name="remember"]').prop('checked'); 

    if ($("#loginUsername").val() === '') {
        $("#loginUsername").parent().addClass('has-error');
        $("#loginUsername").focus();
        //errCount++;
    } else if($("#loginPassword").val() === '') {
        $("#loginPassword").parent().addClass('has-error');
        $("#loginPassword").focus();
    } else {
        $("#loginUsername").parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $.ajax({
            url: "form_login_process.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'Username': username,
                'Password': password,
                'Remember' : remember
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data);
            }
```

The AJAX response shows `"on"`.

form_login_process.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once './include/db_connection.php';
require_once './functions/functions.php';



    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $Remember = $_POST['Remember'];




  $sql = "select * from signup where username = '$Username' and password = '$Password'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)

  {
    if(!empty($_POST['Remember']))
    {
        setcookie("username", $Username,time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        setcookie("pass", $Password,time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));

    }
    else
    {
        //if without clicked on checkbox the cookie still exist then destroy it 
        if(isset($_POST['Username']))
        {
            setcookie("username", "", time()-3600);

        }

        if(isset($_POST['Password']))
        {
            setcookie("username", "", time()-3600);
        }


        }

      echo 'true';
      $_SESSION['username'] = $Username;
  }
  else
  {
      echo "false";
  }
```

Comment: Could you add the code that trigger the form submit ?

Comment: see my edited question

Comment: Post also the code in `form_login_process.php`.

Comment: Side-note: get into the habit of [caching your jQuery objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849692/jquery-object-to-cache-or-not-to-cache) to avoid unnecessary lookups.

Comment: @Mikey
see my edit

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where it prints out `on`

Comment: @Mikey
But the question is why it's automatically make check-box selected whenever we enters the login button???